# Why is my GStreamer element in my pipleline not getting linked?

Tags: python, gstreamer, icecast

I am currently trying to stream an MP3 file from disk to icecast2 using
gstreamer in Python. I am having trouble getting it to work. My initial test
using an `alsasink` to get direct, local audio output worked. But once I switch
to `shout2send` it stops working. From the logs I can figure out that some
elements are not properly linked. This is also visible in the generated
pipeline graph. But I don't understand *why* they are not linked. And how I
should properly do that.

My guess is that shout2send somehow does not include file format information which can then not be properly back-propagated such that the dynamic pads are properly triggered. But that's a fairly wild guess.

I have the following simple gstreamer script:

```
import logging
import os

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject  # NOQA

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def bus_call(bus, message, loop):
    if message.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        LOG.debug('End of Stream')
        loop.quit()
    elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug = message.parse_error()
        LOG.error('!! Error %s: Debug INFO: %s', err, debug)
        loop.quit()
    elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.STATE_CHANGED:
        old, new, pending = message.parse_state_changed()
        LOG.debug('State changed from %s to %s (pending=%s)',
                old.value_name, new.value_name, pending.value_name)
    elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.STREAM_STATUS:
        type_, owner = message.parse_stream_status()
        LOG.debug('Stream status changed to %s (owner=%s)',
                type_.value_name, owner.name)
    elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.DURATION_CHANGED:
        LOG.debug('Duration changed')
    else:
        LOG.debug('!! Unknown message type: %r', message.type)
    return True


def pad_factory(element):
    def pad_added(src, pad):
        target = element.sinkpads[0]
        pad_name = '%s:%s' % (pad.get_parent_element().name, pad.name)
        tgt_name = '%s:%s' % (target.get_parent_element().name, target.name)
        LOG.debug('New dynamic pad %s detected on %s. Auto-linking it to %s',
                pad_name, src.name, tgt_name)
        pad.link(target)
    return pad_added


def debug_event(*args, **kwargs):
    LOG.debug('Debug Event: %r, %r', args, kwargs)


def play(filename):
    LOG.info('Playing %r', filename)
    Gst.init(None)

    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

    # Create pipeline elements
    filesrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make('filesrc')
    filesrc.set_property('location', filename)
    audioconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('audioconvert')
    decodebin = Gst.ElementFactory.make('decodebin')
    decodebin.connect('pad-added', pad_factory(audioconvert))
    audioresample = Gst.ElementFactory.make('audioresample')
    audioresample.connect('pad-added', debug_event)
    shout = Gst.ElementFactory.make('shout2send')
    shout.set_property('mount', "/stream.mp3")
    shout.set_property('port', 8001)
    shout.set_property('username', "stream")
    shout.set_property('password', "supersecret")

    # Add elements to pipeline
    pipeline.add(filesrc)
    pipeline.add(decodebin)
    pipeline.add(audioconvert)
    pipeline.add(audioresample)
    pipeline.add(shout)

    # Link pipeline
    filesrc.link(decodebin)
    # decodebing is dynamically linked to audioconvert by pad_factory
    audioconvert.link(audioresample)
    audioresample.link(shout)

    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()

    # Start playback
    GObject.threads_init()
    loop = GObject.MainLoop()
    bus.connect('message', bus_call, loop)

    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    try:
        loop.run()
    except Exception:
        LOG.exception('Exception raised during main loop')
    LOG.info('Finished playback, cleaning up')
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

    Gst.debug_bin_to_dot_file(
        pipeline,
        Gst.DebugGraphDetails.ALL,
        'supersimple-debug-graph')


try:
    from gouge.colourcli import Simple
    Simple.basicConfig(level=0)
except ImportError:
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(level=0)

os.environ["GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR"] = "/tmp"
os.putenv('GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DIR_DIR', '/tmp')
os.putenv('GST_DEBUG', '3')
play('/var/mp3/Tagged/The Pretty Reckless/Who You Selling For/02 Oh My God.mp3')
```

Running the above script gives me the following output:

```
INFO:__main__:Playing '/var/mp3/Tagged/The Pretty Reckless/Who You Selling For/02 Oh My God.mp3'
0:00:00.013040847   449 0x55bf7eeebc90 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3491:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc0> pad not activated yet
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_NULL to GST_STATE_READY (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_NULL to GST_STATE_READY (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_NULL to GST_STATE_READY (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_NULL to GST_STATE_READY (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_NULL to GST_STATE_READY (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_NULL to GST_STATE_READY (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_NULL to GST_STATE_READY (pending=GST_STATE_PLAYING)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_READY to GST_STATE_PAUSED (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_READY to GST_STATE_PAUSED (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:Stream status changed to GST_STREAM_STATUS_TYPE_CREATE (owner=typefind)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_READY to GST_STATE_PAUSED (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_READY to GST_STATE_PAUSED (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:Stream status changed to GST_STREAM_STATUS_TYPE_ENTER (owner=typefind)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_NULL to GST_STATE_READY (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
0:00:00.018070819   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TDOR' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018098545   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TLAN' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018111322   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TMED' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018125146   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TSO2' to GStreamer tag
DEBUG:__main__:Stream status changed to GST_STREAM_STATUS_TYPE_CREATE (owner=id3demux0)
0:00:00.018142560   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018177535   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:208:gst_tag_from_id3_user_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 user tag 'Artists' of type 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018202931   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018223671   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018244385   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018261488   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:208:gst_tag_from_id3_user_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 user tag 'MusicBrainz Album Release Country' of type 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018281367   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018298526   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:208:gst_tag_from_id3_user_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 user tag 'MusicBrainz Album Status' of type 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018315989   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_READY to GST_STATE_PAUSED (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
0:00:00.018334832   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:208:gst_tag_from_id3_user_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 user tag 'MusicBrainz Album Type' of type 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018355051   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018375697   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018392442   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:208:gst_tag_from_id3_user_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 user tag 'MusicBrainz Release Group Id' of type 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018416280   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018435989   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:208:gst_tag_from_id3_user_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 user tag 'MusicBrainz Release Track Id' of type 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018454110   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
DEBUG:__main__:Stream status changed to GST_STREAM_STATUS_TYPE_ENTER (owner=id3demux0)
0:00:00.018490954   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:208:gst_tag_from_id3_user_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 user tag 'Release type' of type 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018516954   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018529746   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:208:gst_tag_from_id3_user_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 user tag 'Rip date' of type 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018539401   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018547040   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:208:gst_tag_from_id3_user_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 user tag 'SCRIPT' of type 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018554901   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018566128   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:208:gst_tag_from_id3_user_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 user tag 'Source' of type 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018573992   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018581258   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:208:gst_tag_from_id3_user_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 user tag 'originalyear' of type 'TXXX' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018588932   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'UFID' to GStreamer tag
0:00:00.018601234   449 0x55bf7ed9f450 FIXME                  id3v2 gstid3tag.c:144:gst_tag_from_id3_tag: Cannot map ID3v2 tag 'WXXX' to GStreamer tag
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_NULL to GST_STATE_READY (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:Stream status changed to GST_STREAM_STATUS_TYPE_CREATE (owner=mpegaudioparse0)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_READY to GST_STATE_PAUSED (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:New dynamic pad decodebin0:src_0 detected on decodebin0. Auto-linking it to audioconvert0:sink
DEBUG:__main__:Stream status changed to GST_STREAM_STATUS_TYPE_ENTER (owner=mpegaudioparse0)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_NULL to GST_STATE_READY (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_READY to GST_STATE_PAUSED (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
DEBUG:__main__:Duration changed
DEBUG:__main__:State changed from GST_STATE_READY to GST_STATE_PAUSED (pending=GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING)
0:00:00.023287750   449 0x55bf7ed8ccf0 WARN         audio-resampler audio-resampler.c:274:convert_taps_gint32_c: can't find exact taps
0:00:00.023595388   449 0x55bf7ed8ccf0 WARN               baseparse gstbaseparse.c:3608:gst_base_parse_loop:<mpegaudioparse0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.023617643   449 0x55bf7ed8ccf0 WARN               baseparse gstbaseparse.c:3608:gst_base_parse_loop:<mpegaudioparse0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
0:00:00.023991939   449 0x55bf7ed8ccf0 WARN            audiodecoder gstaudiodecoder.c:1609:gst_audio_decoder_drain:<mad0> audio decoder push buffers failed
ERROR:__main__:!! Error gst-stream-error-quark: Internal data stream error. (1): Debug INFO: gstbaseparse.c(3608): gst_base_parse_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpegAudioParse:mpegaudioparse0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
INFO:__main__:Finished playback, cleaning up
```

The generated pipeline image looks like this:

[image: gstreamer pipeline representation]

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet :(